# Testing for 1-level factors in R

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

I have a very large dataset that I'm breaking down into smaller data frames based on one of the factors: state. Unfortunately, for some states, I have very little data (Alaska, for example). When I run my basic model on the smaller data frames I get problems with one of the factors (a gender variable that's only 'M' or 'F').

I'm using a loop to set each state's data frame. I was planning on building an if statement that would only run the model if it didn't have a 1-level factor. But I don't know how to build that if.

```
states_list<-c("AK", ... "WY") # shortened for brevity
resultsList<-list()
j<-1
for (i in states_list){
    temp_data<-raw[raw$state==i,]
    fac <- min(factor(temp_data) # <- Part I don't have right
    if(fac > 1){
        model<-lm(y_var~gender,data=temp_data)
        resultsList[[j]]<-summary(model)
    } else {
        print(i)
        print("doesn't have enough data points")
    }
    j=j+1
}
```

Thanks
-W

Comment: `if(length(levels(diamonds$cut))>1)` only returns TRUE if the column `cut` from `diamonds` has more than one factor level. Is that what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah I think that'll do. Let me go test.

Comment: You might want to use `state.abb` rather than rewriting it.

Comment: @Florian I now got this error:
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
Calls: factor -> sort.list

Comment: It seems that what you want is `fac <- length(unique(temp_data$gender))`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use for loops and I'd strongly recommend using the `broom` package to save your models output as a dataframe, so you can access any value you need.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

# example dataframe
dt = data.frame(state = c(rep("AA",20), rep("BB",15)),
                gender = c(rep("M",10), rep("F",10), rep("M",15)),
                value = rnorm(35, 100, 5), stringsAsFactors = F)

dt %>%
  group_by(state) %>%                                # for each state
  mutate(NumUniqueGenders = n_distinct(gender)) %>%  # count how many unique values of gender you have (and add it for each row)
  filter(NumUniqueGenders == 2) %>%                  # keep only rows the belong to a state with both M and F
  do(tidy(lm(value ~ gender, data=.))) %>%       # run model and save output as a dataframe
  ungroup                                            # forget the grouping


# # A tibble: 2 x 6
#     state        term   estimate std.error  statistic      p.value
#     <chr>       <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
#   1    AA (Intercept) 99.9643476  1.092526 91.4983355 1.787784e-25
#   2    AA     genderM  0.6236803  1.545066  0.4036594 6.912182e-01
```

So, in the end you'll get a dataframe that has 2 rows for each state. One for the intercept and one for gender.

Comment: Sorry for a nitpicking, but should the do line be `do(tidy(lm(y_var ~ gender, data=.))) %>%    `?

Comment: Yes, you're right as the command uses `data=.` so no need for `$`.